# Just how many logs can two woodchucks chuck in a minute?

Tags: enigmatic-puzzle, story

Disaster has struck on your tree farm! You drove up yesterday from the city to find that just over half of your trees were down! Your trees had been set up in a 21x21 grid, and it looked like a random assortment of them had beed felled and demolished over the past few weeks since you'd been here last. As an excellent tracker, you scoured the area for tracks, and discovered that woodchucks had been responsible. In a panic, you decided to cut your losses, and ordered all the rest of your trees be harvested while you decided what to do about the woodchucks.

You spent that night in your office at the tree farm. The next morning you awoke to find a note on the doorstep.

> **Just How Many Logs Can Two Woodchucks Chuck in a Minute?**
>
> You fool! We spent weeks setting this up to answer the age old question about how many logs we can chuck! We had the answer, but when you cut down the rest of the trees, our work was destroyed, and now you'll never know... unless you can recreate our work!
>
> All we can give you are these notes our woodchuck cartographers made while they were perparing to create a map of which trees we felled. Their vocabulary isn't very extensive, so we think you have your work cut out for you. If you can make any sense of it, you should be able to figure out how many logs us two chuckers can chuck in a minute.
>
> Signed,
> The Woodchucks

Underneath that note, you found another piece of paper with two columns:

**EDIT: I'M SO SORRY! There was an error in this table. The second line under West side was missing one letter A. It is correct now: A A A Oak A A**

| West Side: | North Side: |
| --- | --- |
| Sapling Oak Sapling | Sapling A Ax Sapling |
| A A A Oak A A | A A Ax A A |
| A Oak A A A A Oak A | A Oak A A A Oak A |
| A Oak A Tree A Oak A | A Oak A A A A Oak A |
| A Oak A A Ax A Oak A | A Oak A A A Oak A |
| A A A A A A | A A A A A A |
| Sapling A A A Sapling | Sapling A A A Sapling |
| Ax Ax | Tree |
| A A Ax Oak Oak | A Ax Stick Oak |
| A Tree Ax A Ax | Oak A A Ax Oak |
| A Forest Ax Oak | Ax Oak Ax A A Ax |
| Ax A A A A Tree | Oak A A Stick |
| Oak A A A | Oak A Ax Forest Ax |
| A A A A Oak | Ax A Tree |
| Sapling A A A Ax | A A Oak A A Sapling |
| A A A Ax Oak A | Ax A A A A A |
| A Oak A Oak Ax Ax | Ax A Ax A Oak A |
| A Oak A Ax A Ax | Oak A A Ax A A Oak A |
| A Oak A A Rainforest | Ax Oak Ax A A Oak A |
| A A A A A Ax | A A A Ax A A A A |
| Sapling Ax A A A | A Ax A Sapling |

Can you answer the woodchucks' question?

Comment: I thought I had a nice plausible theory for what was going on, and it still looks broadly plausible, but it seems to me like it lands me with a contradiction rather quickly. @Stevish would you be so kind as to double-check the first three entries in the left column, and the last seven in the right column? (Note: this is not the _exact_ set of things needed for the contradiction; I am adding a bit of fuzz in the hope of making this comment less informative to others who would prefer not to be spoiled :-).)

Comment: For the avoidance of doubt: I bet the error is in fact mine (most likely my nice plausible theory is wrong).

Comment: my revised version is looking quite reasonable, but after a while it still runs into contradictions. I've double-checked my transcriptions and sought computerized help. @Stevish despite the above the error is still probably mine, but I'd be glad if you'd double-check the puzzle...

Comment: Yes, @GarethMcCaughan, you did find an error. As if puzzles weren't hard enough when they were written correctly! I was only able to find one error, though, and that's on the second line of the west side.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It seems worthy of note that

> of our repertoire of short tree-related words, no two have the same length. You'd think there might be "wood" as well as "tree" or "branch" as well as "forest" or something, but no.

This suggests

> interpreting those words as *numbers* according to their lengths

which in turn suggests

> that what we have here is a nonogram.

The most obvious way to try to make that work is

> by taking the "west side" entries in the table to describe run-lengths from west to east, and the "north side" entries to describe run-lengths from north to south -- i.e., all in the same order as nonogram clues are usually written.

Unfortunately this runs into two kinds of trouble.

> The first is an outright contradiction at the top right, which one arrives at very quickly. The second is that all those 7s and 1-3-1s rather quickly start to look like we're drawing a *QR code* (I think 21x21 cells may in fact be the *minimal* size for a valid QR code), but the synchronization-pattern squares are in the wrong places: they should be at top left, top right, and bottom left.

The second bit of trouble suggests a possible fix:

> maybe the "north side" numbers need to be understood to run from south to north. (But the "west side" ones still need to run west to east; otherwise we have an equivalent grid rotated 180 degrees and the contradiction is still there, and also that would put the squares in the wrong places again.)

In this case we can

> solve the nonogram (there are online solvers, but I did it by hand; I don't think the solution process is so fascinating as to be worth showing all the steps; probably there are ways to use Clever Reasoning to avoid ever having to "case-split" on what's in a particular cell, but I ended up doing that twice) to get this:
>
> ```
>                          1                           1   1
>                        1 3 1                         3 1 1
>                        3 1 3 1         2       7 1 1 1 3 1
>                      1 1 1 1 1 7     3 1   2   1 1 3 1 1 1
>                    7 1 1 1 1 1 1   3 2 1 5 6   1 1 1 2 1 2 7
>                    2 2 1 1 1 1 1   5 1 2 1 2 4 3 1 2 1 2 1 1
>                    1 1 3 3 3 1 1   2 1 3 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 3 1 2
>                    7 1 1 1 1 1 7 4 1 3 2 3 3 2 1 2 2 3 2 1 1
>                  +-------------------------------------------+
> 7 3 7            | # # # # # # #       # # #   # # # # # # # |
> 1 1 1 3 1 1      | #           #   #   # # #   #           # |
> 1 3 1 1 1 1 3 1  | #   # # #   #   #     #     #   # # #   # |
> 1 3 1 4 1 3 1    | #   # # #   #   # # # #     #   # # #   # |
> 1 3 1 1 2 1 3 1  | #   # # #   #     #   # #   #   # # #   # |
> 1 1 1 1 1 1      | #           #     #     #   #           # |
> 7 1 1 1 7        | # # # # # # #   #   #   #   # # # # # # # |
> 2 2              |                 # #   # #                 |
> 1 1 2 3 3        | #           #   # #     # # #     # # #   |
> 1 4 2 1 2        | #   # # # #   # #   #   # #               |
> 1 6 2 3          |   #         # # # # # #   # #     # # #   |
> 2 1 1 1 1 4      | # #   #   #   #           #   # # # #     |
> 3 1 1 1          |             # # #   #   #       #       # |
> 1 1 1 1 3        |                 #   #   #     #   # # #   |
> 7 1 1 1 2        | # # # # # # #       #       #       # #   |
> 1 1 1 2 3 1      | #           #     #       # #   # # #   # |
> 1 3 1 3 2 2      | #   # # #   #       # # #   # #       # # |
> 1 3 1 2 1 2      | #   # # #   #       # #   #     # #       |
> 1 3 1 1 X        | #   # # #   #     #   # # # # # # # # # # |
> 1 1 1 1 1 2      | #           #     #     #     #   # #     |
> 7 2 1 1 1        | # # # # # # #   # #     #   #         #   |
>                  +-------------------------------------------+
> ```

and then

> on turning this QR code into an image and feeding it to an online decoder (one could in principle do *this* bit by hand as well, but I don't wanna) we get a decode of `Title Word 6`.

So it seems that the answer to the title question is

> two.

Comment: Say, you might know the answer to this. rot13(Vf vg gehr gung perngvat n frg bs ababtenz pyhrf sebz na neovgenel vzntr znl erfhyg va n ababtenz chmmyr jvgu ab havdhr fbyhgvba?)

Comment: Yes. Consider rot13(n 2k2 tevq, jvgu gjb funqrq pryyf va bccbfvgr pbearef). This gives you rot13(gur fnzr pyhrf jurgure lbh pubbfr gur AR naq FJ pbearef be gur AJ naq FR pbearef).

Comment: It appears to be rot13(zvffvat gur fznyy fdhner ba gur obggbz-evtug), making it invalid. Interestingly, though, the "rot13(gvzvat cnggreaf)" seem to be present.

Comment: Sorry, just saw all these comments. You are indeed very close. I'm going to double check all the numbers now.

Comment: You do have at least one error. Your interpretation of the second line in west side doesn't match. I'll keep looking, and update you on my final findings. It's possible we both made mistakes!

Comment: Your interpretations of the cartographers' notes are all correct here with the exception of the mistake I made on the second line of the west side. It should have been written A A A Oak A A. The rest should be solveable with what you have written down.

Comment: My mistake really does scramble a good portion of your map though, and I regret all the extra work you had to do to prove my mistake. I'm so ashamed.

Comment: @codewarrior0, you're right in your comment. There are a lot of ways for these to be non-unique and unsolveable. I had to work through several different versions of this map before finding one that was both solveable and one that could be done with no guessing. It took way more work than I had predicted. That's part of why it was so frustrating that I published it with a mistake in the clues.

Comment: @Stevish Not to worry; mistakes happen. Anyway, I've made the appropriate change and indeed everything seems to work now. Thanks!

Comment: Well done! I knew from the first hidden part of your answer that you were on the right track and would solve it. I wrestled with which way to do the North Side clues since both ways, depending on the interpretation, could result in something unsolveable. But good job figuring it out!

Comment: You could have detected earlier that I was on the right track: there's a reason why I speciflcally described things as looking rot13(dhvgr ernfbanoyr) in one of my comments on the question... :-)